# Gate-source voltage waveform in brushless motor drive

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, powermosfet

What should be the gate-source voltage waveform of the upper side MOSFETs in a brushless motor drive with a trapezoidal control method?
[image: upper side Mosfets gate-source voltage]

Are these parts marked in red in the picture above normal?

There is no such thing at the bottom side MOSFETs
[image: bottom side gate-source voltage wave form]

Schematic:
[image]
#################################

**Update:**

After I increased the bootstrap capacitors from 100 to 400 nF, the high side MOSFETs Vgs waveform became like this, but the problem persists:
[image]

PWM output waveform:

CH1 : PA10_out (Yellow)

CH2 : PB15_out (Blue)

[image]

Comment: Please post a schematic because it's impossible to answer without one.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes I added it

Comment: Please turn off the grid and export with eligible text.

Comment: Show us the waveforms at PA10_OUT and PB15_OUT on the same display (using 2 channels).

Comment: @BruceAbbott Requested waveforms added

Comment: What generates the PWM signals? Some algorithms may not chop all switches at all times to save on switching losses.

Comment: So that's ~1 us of dead-time, right? The 'abnormal' parts you ringed in red show no PWM. Does the PWM signal have a similar pattern? If so, is that a problem or not?

Comment: @BruceAbbott There are no abnormal conditions in pwm signals ,PWM signals are clean and noise-free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was finally able to solve this problem, the problem was in the pull down resistors on the MOSFET gate, the high values ​​of this resistance caused the MOSFET to turn on unintentionally, also its complete removal added to the severity of the problem, by reducing the value from 10K to 500R, solved the problem completely

Answer (score 1):

A couple things of note:

- IR2110 isn't a very strong driver. The 10Ω gate resistors, with or without diodes, essentially don't do anything.  Values on the order of 47Ω are needed to have a significant impact on rise/fall time.  Most likely, just one resistor to dampen potential oscillation will suffice.
- This is also necessary to ensure good sharing of turn-on current between the parallel transistors. In general, gate threshold voltages vary between parts, meaning one turns on earlier; with separate, significant (~47Ω or larger) gate resistors, they turn on closer to the same time.
- Because it's not very fast, the maximum switching frequency should probably be on the low side to save on switching losses.  Perhaps 20kHz or thereabouts.
- The pull-down 10ks draw significant current from the bootstrap capacitor.  These could just as well be removed, as the driver starts in a driven-low output state.
- The bootstrap can be recharged by pulsing low periodically, ensuring a maximum time limit in the output-high state.  Alternately, clamp the output duty cycle to avoid 100%. Whichever way makes the most sense for your control.
- Since you show the low side MOSFETs pulsing constantly, perhaps you can swap the control scheme so that the high side is pulsing constantly and the low side is maintained (100% duty cycle during the phase).  This trivially solves the issue, if it is possible/permissible.

Comment: Can BEMF voltage be the cause of this phenomenon?

Comment: Not based on the information provided.

Comment: Really confused, I tried most of the tips given but still nothing changed :(

Comment: Add waveforms showing the minimum pulse rate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be your bootstrap power supply discharging. I'm not sure why the second pulse is higher, and an explanation of what's going on in the "filled" area would be useful.

When the high-side device is turned on, it is no longer charged through the bootstrap diode, and only has the charge stored in the 3x 22nF capacitors. With the output driven high, it will also power R47 (10kΩ), giving you a RC time constant of 0.66 milliseconds.

If you held the output high for longer, you would probably see the exponential decay more clearly defined... right before the high side transistor turns off and possibly causes havoc.

The simple solution is to increase your bootstrap capacitance, and ensure that you don't leave the driver in a state with the high-side device tied high for too long.

Comment: According to what you said, I calculated the bootstrap capacitor using the equation: Cg = Qg/VGE ==> CG= 34.69nf For two parallel MOSFETs , Therefore, we choose the value of the bootstrap capacitor 10 times larger than this value which is equal to: Cboot = 34.69 x 10 , And I put a value of 400nf for the bootstrap capacitor,I put the picture of the waveform after adding the bootstrap capacitors